# nginx load balancer occasionally fails

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

We have a new nginx load balancer and occasionally, nginx is throwing up this error message:

"Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable. Please try again later."

There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason - the link will fail, but if I refresh, it'll work. It's inconsistent.

I should also mention that our nginx error log doesn't show anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you *refresh* what? The browser? Does it load the other (working) page when you refresh, or the previously failed one? Mind showing `nginx.conf` and the `sites-enabled/yoursite` config files?

Comment: Turns out I just needed to tweak some settings. I took some advice from this page and things are much more stable:

http://dak1n1.com/blog/12-nginx-performance-tuning